# Get class created at runtime

Tags: java, file, class, classpath

I'm trying to copy a .java file containing a class (MyTestClass in package "test") from some place on my disk. I want to get class which this file contains. Maybe my code will be useful. This is my code:

```
File generatedFile = new File( DIR_CONTAINING_FILE + "/" + className + ".java" );
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory( generatedFile, COPY_FILE_DIR );
Class cl = Class.forName( "test.MyTestClass" );
```

Copying file works fine. It shows where it has to be.

When I copy my file to COPY_FILE_DIR manually and then start program it will work, it will find my class. But when I start my program without copying file first (I mean when I let it do to my program) I got ClassNotFoundException. When I refresh directories there's my file, so it has been copied perfectly.

In this moment I can start my program again and.. magic! it will find my class! Looks like I need to refresh directories from java or do something else.. I don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to compile the Java source file first before you can load the class.

Comment: In order to load a class it must be compiled first. So for `Class.forName("test.MyTestClass")` to work there must be a `MyTestClass.class` file on the class path of the program you are running. My guess is when you manually copy you are using some IDE that compiles the .java file for you. If you really want to you can compile the class at runtime and load it using a custom class loader (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

Comment: How do you start the application? On the second start, the classpath contained the compiled class, from the source you copied to the actual folder... It seems that running your app triggers compiling the sources too

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'll have to get familiar with the [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) API to do this. It's not really important where you store your `.java` Files - they have to be compiled to bytecode before you can try to use them inside the runtime.